# SingleDatePicker focused (react-dates) => returning an error

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, react-dates

The SingleDatePicker from react-dates returning an error: Invalid prop `focused` of type `object` supplied to `withStyles(SingleDatePicker)`, expected `boolean`

Here the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-mclaren-2w5q8?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

apparently this solved the issue:

```
 const onFocusChange = ({ focused }) => {
    setFocused(focused);
 };

<SingleDatePicker
  onFocusChange={onFocusChange}
/>
```